# GetAnalyzerDiagnosticsAsync returns nothing if a DiagnosticAnalyzer has an empty Initialize

Tags: c#, code-analysis, roslyn

I am writing a method which gets all the `Diagnostic`s for a `Project` for a set of `DiagnosticAnalyzer`s:

```
private static async Task<ImmutableArray<Diagnostic>> GetDiagnosticsAsync(
    Project project,
    ImmutableArray<DiagnosticAnalyzer> analyzers)
{
    var compilation = await project.GetCompilationAsync();
    var withAnalyzers = compilation.WithAnalyzers(analyzers);
    var diagnostics = await withAnalyzers.GetAnalyzerDiagnosticsAsync();

    return diagnostics;
}
```

This works fine if all the `DiagnosticAnalyzer`s in `analyzers` have their `Initialize(AnalysisContext)` method containing some register call:

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.Register...(...);
}
```

However if any of them have an empty implementation

```
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    // nothing here
}
```

then `diagnostics.Count() == 0`.

Have I misunderstood what the behavior for `GetAnalyzerDiagnosticsAsync()` and `DiagnosticAnalyzers` are and therefore this a correct thing for it to be doing? Or is this a bug in Roslyn? Or is there another method I should be using? Or something else?

---

I'm tempted to think that this is a error in Roslyn (as such I have [opened an issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/3116)). Digging into the source code and debugging results that the difference occurs in `CompilationWithAnalyzers._driver.DiagnosticQueue` - when it works this has the desired `Count` but is `0` when the issue occurs.

The plot thickens...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this *was* a bug with Roslyn, which has now been fixed:

- [Closed issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/3116)
- [Pull request](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/commit/96bbb86dd1f216cef0d7a8500b063b76c6b7366b#diff-f8159931eab67875a9504f78827742b7R637)